# JasperReports: print ArrayList to TextFields in template

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

I have this code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource;

public class TestReport {
    public void runReport() {
        try {
            List<Text> list = new ArrayList<Text>(3);
            list.add(new Text("a1"));
            list.add(new Text("b1"));
            list.add(new Text("c1"));

            Map parameters = new HashMap();
            parameters.put("text", list);           

            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport("report1.jasper", parameters, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));

            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, "report1.pdf");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private class Text {        
        private String txt;     
        public Text() {}                
        public Text(String txt) {this.txt = txt;}
        public void setTxt(String txt) {this.txt = txt;}        
        public String getTxt() {return txt;}
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TestReport().runReport();
    }
}
```

I need to generate PDF which have "Text Fields" in "Detail" section.

[image]

I try to use "JavaBeans set datasource" but it crash with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.<clinit>(JRLoader.java:68)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPropertiesUtil.loadProperties(JRPropertiesUtil.java:99)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.initProperties(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:94)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.<init>(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:71)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.DefaultJasperReportsContext.<clinit>(DefaultJasperReportsContext.java:59)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.getDefaultInstance(JasperFillManager.java:85)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:915)
    at TestReport.runReport(TestReport.java:26)
    at TestReport.main(TestReport.java:49)
```

I have bad template. Can you please help me (or send me example template) how can I create working template like at image? First text field should contain "a1", second "b1",...

Answer (score 0):

The error says 'LogFactory' class cannot be found, which means you are missing commons-logging.jar, which JasperReports uses.
As for the template, you could use a List (component) or a Table in the Detail and set its datasource to be the list you are sending ($P("text") or $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}). 
Also, it is not necessary to send the list both as a parameter or a datasource. You could either send it as a parameter (which in some, more complex cases - with multiple lists and tables, is the way to go) and set the datasource as a JREmptyDataSource, or send it as a datasource and remove it from the parameters, which in your case would be enough.